# Is it MVVM friendly to use other ViewModels as bindable properties?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, freshmvvm

First a little backstory: I am studying Xamarin for a month now, and I am about to start my first project.

I have a need where I have like **4 nested "generations" of a relational database**, that I have to include in one View.

When I start to nest stuff, I am forced to move some Commands (ViewModel code) into the Model.

I want to avoid this at all cost, thus the question arise:

*Is it MVVM friendly to use other ViewModels as bindable properties, like in the following Example?*

ViewModels:

```
public class MainViewModel : FreshBasePageModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<OtherViewModel> OtherCollection { get; set; }
}

public class OtherViewModel: FreshBasePageModel 
{
    public Command SomeCommand { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this in the Views:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ListView ItemsSource={Binding OtherCollection} SelectedItem={Binding SomeCommand}>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
```

This approach seems Okay to me, but this is my first ever MVVM project, and I wonder if this is how you do stuff.

I use [FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) as the backing framework, and it uses conventions for bindings, so the view is automatically bound to its **namesake** partner.

Also, if you'd like to look at my nested lists, see below:
[image]

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1):

**By default this behaviour isn't supported because a control only has a `DataContext` o `BindableContex`** and this class is where the compiler look for your binding properties and commands.

**In MVVM, you should only use a ViewModel for each View** so your approach isn't frequent.

However I think that you could use the code that you proposed if you use the Path binding property and you have other control which its BindableContex is `OtherViewModel`

Comment: Aha thanks, basically as the name suggest, the ViewModel is a Model for some View. Do you have any idea how to approach this? I am open to completely change my approach.

Comment: As I understand it you can have a backing class (view model) for anything that can accept a delegate, so a list inside a list can have a different view model than it's parent. This is definately something that you do in Xamarin.iOS, is it really not acceptable in forms? =)

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I have tried a bit iOS development and  I know how its delegate system works, however it breaks a bit the [MVVM pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) I also have seen people who use more than one view models if the view is very complex (mainly in WPF, desktop apps)

Comment: @ganchito55 I think you're right though, It is a bit messy using more than one VM, it's just interesting how there are so many occassions where it seems like the only option. I think as long as the view doesn't handle any of the data manipulation it's probably safe to have a few view models. But honestly I'm not sure what the best practice would be. =)

Comment: @Kokolo I don't know what exactly that command makes however you can use only one ViewModel and then in the command call other methods. For these methods you can use the model classes or an auxiliar class, in this case your command could follow the [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

Comment: @ganchito55 The command is a dummy command to see how things work with each other. How can I use one ViewModel and have all commands in the view bound to that ViewModel? BTW I didn't understand fully your suggestion. Do you say so use one ViewModel, and an auxiliary class in-between to provide help for the Commands and Bindings?

Comment: @Kokolo I tell you that there are many approach to use MVVM, if the VM is very large, I prefer to use it only to manage the interactions and binding the data and then use other classes for process the data. But all depends how large/complex is your app.

Comment: @ganchito55 In my case, the problem is not that he VM is large, but that the nesting is tripled in the view. How can I have triple nested relation in a same view that uses commands from the same VM?